# I recently started learning cycles detection in Graphs. How can I detect the cycle with the code below? The code show no cycle but there is a cycle

Tags: javascript

```js
/* 
Cycle Detection in Undirected Graph using DFS
There is a cycle in the graph below but my code shows there is no cycle.
I am using DFS to detect the cycle here.
I am using visited and dfVisited arrays to mark the nodes.
I have spent so much trying to make it work but I don't understand what is wrong
Cycle Detection in Undirected Graph using DFS
There is a cycle in the graph below but my code shows there is no cycle.
I am using DFS to detect the cycle here.
I am using visited and dfVisited arrays to mark the nodes.
I have spent so much trying to make it work but I don't understand what is wrong
Cycle Detection in Undirected Graph using DFS
There is a cycle in the graph below but my code shows there is no cycle.
I am using DFS to detect the cycle here.
I am using visited and dfVisited arrays to mark the nodes.
I have spent so much trying to make it work but I don't understand what is wrong
Cycle Detection in Undirected Graph using DFS
There is a cycle in the graph below but my code shows there is no cycle.
I am using DFS to detect the cycle here.
I am using visited and dfVisited arrays to mark the nodes.
I have spent so much trying to make it work but I don't understand what is wrong
Cycle Detection in Undirected Graph using DFS
There is a cycle in the graph below but my code shows there is no cycle.
I am using DFS to detect the cycle here.
I am using visited and dfVisited arrays to mark the nodes.
I have spent so much trying to make it work but I don't understand what is wrong
*/


class Graph {
  constructor(V) {
    this.V = V;
    this.adj = {}; //Adjacency Matrix
  }
 //Adding vertex 
  addVertex = (v) => {
    if (!this.adj[v]) {
      this.adj[v] = [];
    }
  };
 //Adding edges
  addEdge = (v, u) => {
    this.adj[v].push(u);
  };
//This function detects the cycle
  isCyclicUtil = (source, visited, dfsVisited) => {
    visited[source] = true;
    dfsVisited[source] = true;
    this.adj[source]?.forEach((neighbor) => {
      if (!visited[neighbor] && this.isCyclicUtil(neighbor, visited, dfsVisited))
        return true;
      else if (dfsVisited[neighbor]) return true;
    });
    dfsVisited[source] = false;
    return false;
  };

  hasCycle = () => {
    const visited = Array(this.V).fill(false);
    const dfsVisited = Array(this.V).fill(false);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.V; i++) {
      if (!visited[i] && this.isCyclicUtil(i, visited, dfsVisited)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
  checkCycle = () => {
    if (this.hasCycle()) {
      console.log("Cycle is present.");
    } else {
      console.log("No cycle is present");
    }
  };
}

const graph = new Graph(4);
graph.addVertex(0);
graph.addVertex(1);
graph.addVertex(2);
graph.addVertex(3);
graph.addEdge(0, 1);
graph.addEdge(1, 2);
graph.addEdge(2, 0);
graph.addEdge(2, 3);
graph.checkCycle(); //cycle is present
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The above code doesn't work as expected.  It is supposed to show that there is a cycle in the graph but it shows no cycle instead. I believe  isCyclicUtil method is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `forEach` loop.

You seem to expect that the `forEach` loop will stop making iterations when you execute a `return` in its callback. But that will only return from the callback, not from `isCyclicUtil`. Moreover, the *value* that is returned is completely ignored by the `forEach` internals. It will happily continue the iterations.

You could solve this with with a `for..of` loop, as then these `return` statements apply to the `isCyclicUtil` method and will therefore interrupt the loop and return `true`:

```
    for (const neighbor of this.adj[source]) {
      if (!visited[neighbor] && this.isCyclicUtil(neighbor, visited, dfsVisited))
        return true;
      else if (dfsVisited[neighbor]) return true;
    }
```

Comment: OMG ! :( . I just didn't notice that forEach doesn't return anything.  Thank you so much